# How can I use fancybox resize without the transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, fancybox

I am currently using `$.fancybox.resize()` to reposition fancybox in the middle of the window each time I load new content through ajax. How can I remove the transition effect?

Comment: set `transitionIn` and `transitionOut` API options to `"none"` (fancybox v1.3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of fancybox are you using?

Maybe try something like this during the initialisation

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect: 'none',
  closeEffect: 'none',
  nextEffect: 'none',
  prevEffect: 'none'
});
```

Comment: `$.fancybox.resize()` is for v1.3.4 if you are unaware, otherwise use `$.fancybox.update()` for v2.x ;)